# PHP Return user to script continuously running in background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a PHP script running in the background executing a PHP script reading a big table. At the same time it is sending the results to an API. This is done with unbuffered query.

On the top of this script, I've put

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

To make sure the script runs in the background until it is done. I also have a Javascript that is getting progress report from this script. But, when the page is reloaded, the progress is started again and it will start sending the data again to the API duplicating data.

I was wondering if there is a way to let the user continue on the script. So the script is already running in the background, but is there a way to return the user to the script so it'll be like they never left?

EX:

User starts importing, import is at 200 rows out of 1 million. They refresh the page and the page says 202 rows out of 1 million. 202 mil cause time has past importing more rows while the user has left since script is executing in the background.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: How are you getting progress report via JavaScript?

Comment: I make a AJAX request to the PHP script and the PHP script will echo out a message to AJAX after each row is finished. Therefore the user will be notified of how many rows are imported

Comment: Are you having the user upload a file that imports stuff into a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use websocket to this case. When you will establish new connection to websocket you can store the connection in cookies. Then when you will reload the page you can restablish connection to websocket server. On top of that you need have a websocket server that can read from cookie variables.

Comment: Could you provide a example of this? Setting up a websocket server is no issue, I'm guessing you mean by using something like socket.io

Answer (score 0):

Could this be done with using a cookie ?

Each time it runs, update said cookie then if the page is refreshed use the information in the cookie to start where it left off and update the page ?

Comment: Well the script will keep running in the background cause it'lll be reading big tables such as 300 million rows. The idea is to start the progress be able to leave and have it running, come back any time and check the progress